# Sort object elements and print out a string

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have this function witch returns an object with all the occurrences of each character in a string

```
function count(str){
  var arr = {},
      i = str.length,
      j;
  while( i-- ){
    j = arr[str[i]];
    if(arr[str[i]] = j){
      arr[str[i]] = j+1;
    }
    else arr[str[i]] = 1;
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(count("ra ta ta ratata"));
```

the returned value is {a: 6, t: 4, r: 2,  : 3}
How can I combine the values in order to return a string with the characters sorted by the number of occurrences
it should return "aaaaaatttt   rr"

Comment: So do another loop! Sounds like homework.

Comment: `if(arr[str[i]] = j){` sets `arr[str[i]]` to `j` and return the boolean value of `j`. Also this does nothing because `j` was just set to `arr[str[i]]`, so you don't have anything to compare between them.

Comment: I think the return value should actually be "at r".

Comment: @ArunPJohny: That will sort by the character value, not number of occurances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var o = {a: 6, t: 4, r: 2, z : 3},
    letters = Object.keys(o).sort(function (a, b) {
        return o[b] - o[a];
    }).reduce(function (s, key) {
        return s += Array(o[key] + 1).join(key);
    }, '');

console.log(letters); //aaaaaattttzzzrr
```

Note that `Object.keys` might not be supported, but you can use a shim for it or simply gather the keys by doing something like:

```
var keys = [], k;

for (k in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        keys.push(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `Array(o[key])` suppose to be `Array(o[key] + 1)` ?

Comment: @Vatev, Yeah sorry, fixed!